# Brachistochrone problem with drag

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag, variational-principle, brachistochrone-problem

The original [Brachistochrone problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve) is without friction and drag.  The [Brachistochrone problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) can also be solved analytically with friction. But what would the optimal path be if there was a drag force that was in proportion to the object's speed?